# what is the formal name for success unit tests vs error unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

What is the formal name for "success unit tests" vs "error unit tests"?  In this context I'm refering to a success unit test to validate the primary success scenario and an error unit test to validate an error handling routine.

For creating a user, the success unit test would validate that the user was created successfully.  One error unit test would validate that if the client did not provide a LastName value then the system should return an exception stating "Last Name is required."

So in the domain of unit testing is their a formal/proper name to describe these 2 different types of unit tests?

Comment: They're both just unit tests, but the *"everything worked"* run is sometimes referred to as the [*"happy path"*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path).

Comment: I don't think there's a formal name, but a naming convention for the tests is often used to describe what the expected result is. For example, you might have a test called `CallXXXWithNoLastNameExpectException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between *positive* and *negative* tests.  Negative tests are those with invalid inputs.  For example, a negative number as an input for a square root function could be a negative test.  Thus, a way of looking at negative tests is to understand them as tests that try the 'unspecified' cases.  For such tests, there is often not a specific outcome expected - that's because the behaviour of the system under test is unspecified: What do you expect if you give a negative value to a square root function?  However, there are typically some generic expectations for such tests, like "system will not crash".

Unfortunately, this does not necessarily fit exactly to your scenario: Error handling is typically implemented because of a precise specification how to handle a certain situation.  Thus, the situation is not 'unspecified'.

My recommendation is to use *happy path* testing (as suggested by @jonrshape) or something more descriptive like *success case testing* for the non-error cases, and use a descriptive phrase like *error handling testing* for the, well, error handling tests.

Since different people/teams tend to use different terms for the same things or interpret the same terms in a different way, it may make sense to create a glossary for your/your team's documents, so at least other colleagues know what you mean with the different terms.